# Почему ответ не выводится?

Tags: python

Сколько существует целых значений числа A, при которых формула

((x < A) → (x^2 < 100)) ∧ ((y^2 ≤ 64) → (y ≤ A))

тождественно истинна при любых целых неотрицательных x и y?

Мой код:

```
for a in range(0,1000):
    f=True
    for x in range(1,100):
        for y in range(1,100):
            if ((not (x < a) or (x ** 2 < 100)) and (not(y ** 2 <= 64) or (y <= a))) == False:
                f=False
                if f == True:
                    print(a)
```

Я не вижу в нем ошибки

Comment: главная ошибка в том, что ты f перед проверкой на значение True приравнивниваешь к False, поэтому ответ не выводится

Comment: Я приравниваю f к False только в том случае, если хоть один из x или y не подходит, так как в условии сказано, что при любых значениях x и y, если же f остается True, я и вывожу нужное A

Comment: Вообще непонятно зачем код. Но даже если он нужен, он не отвечает на вопрос «сколько?»

Comment: Вы приравниваете f=False сразу перед проверкой на True, т.е. эта проверка гарантированно никогда не выполняется.

Comment: Спасибо, понял вас

Answer (score 1):

Поправить ваш код не сложно. Нужно исправить число пробелов в последних двух строках. Работает как задумано:

```
for a in range(0,1000):
    f=True
    for x in range(1,100):
        for y in range(1,100):
            if ((not (x < a) or (x ** 2 < 100)) and (not(y ** 2 <= 64) or (y <= a))) == False:
                f=False
    if f == True:
        print(a)
```

Некоторые доработки. Вы знаете логику, значит поймёте пару правил:

```
expr == False    ->    not expr
expr == True     ->        expr
```

Правила применимы только если `expr` имеет булев тип. Так что ещё правило: избегайте неявного приведения выражений другого типа к булеву.

Следующее правило: все операторы в коде одного уровня абстракции. Сейчас не так: смешано вычисление `f` (низкий уровень), проверка и печать (высокий уровень). Прячем вычисление:

```
def check(a):
    f=True
    for x in range(1,100):
        for y in range(1,100):
            if not ((not (x < a) or (x ** 2 < 100)) and (not(y ** 2 <= 64) or (y <= a))):
                f=False
    return f


for a in range(0,1000):
    if check(a):
        print(a)
```

Оптимизация: если единственное действие цикла присвоение константы, прерываем цикл немедленно. Функция `check` делает единственное действие, выходим из неё быстро:

```
def check(a):
    for x in range(1,100):
        for y in range(1,100):
            if not ((not (x < a) or (x ** 2 < 100)) and (not(y ** 2 <= 64) or (y <= a))):
                return False
    return True
```

Бизнес логика смешана с вычислениями. Разделяем:

```
def formula(a, x, y):
    # ((x < A) → (x^2 < 100)) ∧ ((y^2 ≤ 64) → (y ≤ A))
    return (not (x < a) or (x ** 2 < 100)) and (not (y ** 2 <= 64) or (y <= a))


def check(a):
    for x in range(1,100):
        for y in range(1,100):
            if not formula(a, x, y):
                return False
    return True
```

Знай и люби библиотеку языка. [all](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) проверяет что все элементы истинны:

```
def check(a):
    return all(
        formula(a, x, y)
        for x in range(1,100)
        for y in range(1,100)
    )
```

Всё вместе:

```
def formula(a, x, y):
    # ((x < A) → (x^2 < 100)) ∧ ((y^2 ≤ 64) → (y ≤ A))
    return (not (x < a) or (x ** 2 < 100)) and (not (y ** 2 <= 64) or (y <= a))


def check(a):
    return all(
        formula(a, x, y)
        for x in range(1, 100)
        for y in range(1, 100)
    )


for a in range(1000):
    if check(a):
        print(a)
```

> ```
> $ time python formula.py
> 8
> 9
> 10
>
> real  0m0.552s
> user  0m0.548s
> sys   0m0.000s
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Для начала нужно сделать как-то так

```
count = 0
for a in range(0,1000):
    f=True
    for x in range(1,100):
        for y in range(1,100):
            if ((not (x < a) or (x ** 2 < 100)) and (not(y ** 2 <= 64) or (y <= a))) == False:
                if f == True:
                    count += 1
                    print(a)
                    f=False
print(count)
```

Но у тебя какие-то странные значения, почему ты выбрал такой диапазон, для А - 1000 и по 100 для x и y? Есть какое-то дополнительное условие?

Comment: Дополнительных условий нет, просто считаю это оптимальными диапазонами, а добавлять счетчик не стал, так как нужных A обычно бывает не очень много, +-10, я могу и вручную посчитать) Но почему не выводит нужный ответ, не понимаю